# two filled paths one upon the other

Tags: android, android-canvas

I can't manage the following and I hope someone have a hint for me?

I have 2 areas (filled paths)  one upon the other. The lower one is filled completely in blue. The upper one I would like the fill in red partly with a specific pattern ( for example with lines ). So at the end I have a filled area with blue and red striped.

In my tries the upper one overlaps the lower one, so blue is not seen.

I tried to do this with bitmapshader but do not succeed.

```
BitmapShader mShader1 = new BitmapShader(makeBitmap1(),
                                         Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
                                         Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
paint.setShader(mShader1);
canvas.drawPath(cpath.path, paint);

private static Bitmap makeBitmap1() {
    //Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    //Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    //Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(10, 10, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
    c.drawColor(Color.RED);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(0xFF000000);
    //p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    c.drawRect(2, 2, 8, 8, p);
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Why are you painting black rectangles?

Comment: I do not paint black. 0xFF000000 should be transparent. My Result isn't black on the screen. I would like the upper shape to be transparent in the regions where nothing is drawn, so the lower shape is visible. Any hints ?

Comment: 0xFF000000 is black.  0x00000000 is transparent.  0xAARRGGBB, where A is Alpha, R is Red, G is Green, B is Black.